# ipvsadm -L -n suddenly showing no active connections

Tags: squid, pacemaker, corosync

I have a very odd problem in a proxy cluster of four Squid proxies:

One of the machine is the master. The mater is running ldirectord which is checking the availability of all four machines, distributing new client connections.

All over a sudden, after years of operation I'm encountering this problem:

1) The machine serving the master role is not being assigned new connections, old connections are served until a new proxy is assigned to the clients.

2) The other machines are still processing requests, taking over the clients from the master (so far, so good)

3) "ipvsadm -L -n" shows ever-decreasing ActiveConn and InActConn values.

Once I migrate the master role to another machine, "ipvsadm -L -n" is showing lots of active and inactive connections, until after about an hour the same thing happens on the new master.

Datapoint: This happened again this afternoon, and now "ipvsadm -L -n" shows:

```
TCP  141.42.1.215:8080 wlc persistent 1800
  -> 141.42.1.216:8080            Route   1   98         0
  -> 141.42.1.217:8080            Route   1   135        0
  -> 141.42.1.218:8080            Route   1   1          0
  -> 141.42.1.219:8080            Route   1   2          0
```

No change in the numbers quite some time now.

Some more stats (ipvsadm -L --stats -n):

```
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port               Conns   InPkts  OutPkts  InBytes OutBytes
  -> RemoteAddress:Port
TCP  141.42.1.215:8080             1990351 87945600        0   13781M        0
  -> 141.42.1.216:8080              561980 21850870        0    2828M        0
  -> 141.42.1.217:8080              467499 23407969        0    3960M        0
  -> 141.42.1.218:8080              439794 19364749        0    2659M        0
  -> 141.42.1.219:8080              521378 23340673        0    4335M        0
```

Value for "Conns" is constant now for all realservers and the virtual server now. Traffic is still flowing (InPkts increasing).

I examined the output of "ipvsadm -L -n -c" and found:

```
 25 FIN_WAIT
534 NONE
977 ESTABLISHED
```

Then I waited a minute and got:

```
 21 FIN_WAIT
515 NONE
939 ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a local bird installation was injecting router for the IP of the virtual server and thus taking precedence over ARP.